# pass cookie from http response via nginx proxy

Tags: cookies, nginx, docker, proxy, webserver

I have a problem with passing my cookie when I'm running an nginx as a proxy (in a docker container). Here is my configuration of my nginx proxy:

```
    location /test {
            proxy_pass http://test-backend:8080;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    }
```

When I run my backend without the proxy I have the cookie in my response. However, if I run it using the proxy the cookie is not being passed through the proxy. What kind of setting am I missing?

Comment: Does you backend have a different domain name? You may need to use a `proxy_cookie_domain` directive to translate it. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_cookie_domain) for details.

Comment: no the backend runs on the same domain

Comment: In my pretty similar case, the problem was with RewriteRule on apache side:  

`RewriteRule ^/admin/$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]`  

After commenting out, cookie traversal worked perfectly